# whenever used to execute a method rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, whenever

I'm attempting to use the whenever to execute a method every 30 minutes. However I'm having some trouble setting it up.

schedule.rb

```
every 1.minutes do
    runner "Post.winner"
end
```

post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

module Post
    def winner
        #do some stuff that saves a new value in database
```

I don't think the runner is working because the field that I save a value to still shows up as nil in the console.

Answer (score 4):

You most probably do not want to run a controller method (eg you have no request to serve there). Either create a `runner` from a class or module.

```
# schedule.rb
every 30.minutes do
  runner "Post.winner"
end

#lib/post.rb
module Post
  def self.winner
    ...
  end
end
```

or a `rake` task in `lib/tasks/`

```
# schedule.rb
every 30.minutes do
  rake post:winner
end

#lib/tasks/post.rake

namespace :post do    
  desc 'calculate winner'
  task :winner do
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm attempting to use the runner. however, I'm under the impression that it is never being called. I updated the question

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost sure you have a model `Post`. Create a class method:

```
class Post
  ...
  def self.winner
    ...
  end
end
```

But if you are using `Post.winner` only for the schedule, I prefer a rake task as @xlembouras suggested.